# Adding a condition to a regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Given the Javascript below how can I add a condition to the clause? I would like to add a "space" character after a separator only if a space does not already exist. The current code will result in double-spaces if a space character already exists in spacedText.

```
var separators = ['.', ',', '?', '!'];
for (var i = 0; i < separators.length; i++) { 
      var rg = new RegExp("\\" + separators[i], "g"); 
      spacedText = spacedText.replace(rg, separators[i] + " "); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'. , ? ! .,?!foo'.replace(/([.,?!])(?! )/g, '$1 ');
//-> ". , ? ! . , ? ! foo"
```

Means replace every occurence of one of .,?! that is not followed by a space with itself and a space afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following regexp to solve your problem:

```
"Test!Test! Test.Test 1,2,3,4 test".replace(/([!,.?])(?!\s)/g, "$1 ");
// "Test! Test! Test. Test 1, 2, 3, 4 test"
```

The regexp matches any character in the character class `[!,.?]` not followed by a space `(?!\s)`. The parenthesis around the character class means that the matched separator will be contained in the first backreference `$1`, which is used in the replacement string. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A7SMq/) for working example.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a replace of all above characters including a space. In that way you will capture any punctuation and it's trailing space and replace both by a single space.

```
"H1a!. A ?. ".replace(/[.,?! ]+/g, " ")
```

`[.,?! ]` is a chararcter class. It will match either `.`, `,`, `?`, `!` or  and + makes it match atleast once (but if possible multiple times).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code :

```
var nonSpaced= 'Hello World!Which is your favorite number? 10,20,25,30 or other.answer fast.';
var spaced;
var patt = /\b([!\.,\?])+\b/g;

spaced = nonSpaced.replace(patt, '$1 ');
```

If you `console.log` the value of `spaced`, It will be : `Hello World! Which is your favorite number? 10, 20, 25, 30 or other. answer fast.` Notice the number of space characters after the `?` sign , it is only one, and there is not extra space after last `full-stop`.

Answer (score 0):

`spacedText = spacedText.replace(/([\.,!\?])([^\s])/g,"$1 ")`

This means: replace one of these characters (`[\.,!\?]`) followed by a non-whitespace character (`[^\s]`) with the match from first group and a space (`"$1 "`).